# EXT.NET Combobox in gridpanel show value instead of text

Tags: c#, combobox, render, ext.net, gridpanel

I have a big problem in EXT.NET.
I have a gridpanel with a combobox inside.
The combobox work fine but when the grid load, if I click on the combobox for edit, the combobox show me the value instead of text.
If I select one of the possible item in the combobox, save the result and retry to edit the same combobox, at this time the value show is correct (I see the Text and thi is correct.)
Follow my code:

The render function:

```
var StatusRenderer = function (value, st) {
        var ind = st.find("Value", value);
        var r = st.getAt(ind);
        if (Ext.isEmpty(r)) {
            return "";
        }
        return r.data.Text;
    };
```

The column in the gridpanel:

```
<ext:Column ID="ColumnProfilo" runat="server" DataIndex="Profilo" Text="Profilo">
                            <Renderer Handler="return StatusRenderer(value, #{StoreProfilo});" />
                            <Editor>      
                                <ext:ComboBox ID="ComboBoxProfilo" SelectOnFocus="true" EmptyText="Select a Class"  TriggerAction="All" QueryMode="Local" runat="server" DisplayField="Text" ValueField="Value">
                                    <Store>
                                        <ext:Store ID="StoreProfilo" runat="server" AutoLoad="true" >
                                            <Model>
                                                <ext:Model ID="ModelProfilo" runat="server" IDProperty="Value">
                                                    <Fields>
                                                        <ext:ModelField Name="Text" />
                                                        <ext:ModelField Name="Value" />
                                                    </Fields>
                                                </ext:Model>
                                            </Model>            
                                        </ext:Store>
                                    </Store>
                                    <Listeners>
                                        <BeforeQuery Handler="delete queryEvent.combo.lastQuery;" />
                                    </Listeners>
                                </ext:ComboBox>
                            </Editor>
                        </ext:Column>
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: how do you insert items to store?

Answer (score 0):

Please Please Review This Sample and use " instead of Handler="..

http://examples1.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Data_Presentation/Editor_Field_Mapping/